# 42703 ERROR: column "my_nested_column" does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue-data-catalog, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I run a Glue Crawler over a nested JSON data-source on S3 and I tried to query nested fields as per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-query-nested-data.html) via Redshift Spectrum:

```
select c.id , c.my_nested_column.MyField
from my_external_schema.my_table c;
```

But as per title I was getting the error message

```
[42703] ERROR: column "my_nested_column" does not exist
```

which doesn't really make sense as from metadata I can see the field exists. But because of this I'm unable to unnest fields from "my_nested_column".

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations, I noticed that one of the fields of the JSONs being parsed contained a colon within the field name and it was something like `my:field`.

This clashes with the JSON logic and doesn't work really well. I removed this field from the Glue Catalog and afterwards I was able to query the field correctly.

The initial error message I was getting really didn't help but the problem was caused by malformed JSON field name.